# setting an array from simple_xml data

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to create an array of titles from an xml feed using this code:

```
$url = 'https://indiegamestand.com/store/salefeed.php';
$xml = simplexml_load_string(file_get_contents($url));

$on_sale = array();

foreach ($xml->channel->item as $game)
{
    echo $game->{'title'} . "\n";
    $on_sale[] = $game->{'title'};
}

print_r($on_sale);
```

The echo $game->{'title'} . "\n"; returns the correct title, but when setting the title to the array i get spammed with this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )
```

Am I missing something when setting this array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

`$on_sale[] = $game->{'title'}->__toString();`

or even better (in my opinion):

`$on_sale[] = (string) $game->{'title'};`

PHP doesn't know that you want the string value when you add the object to the array, so `__toString()` doesn't get called automatically like it does in the `echo` call. When you cast the object to `string`, `__toString()` is called automatically.

*FYI: You don't really need the curly braces either, this works fine for me:*

`$on_sale[] = (string) $game->title;`